# Core Data not saving integer properly? When changing from NSString to int

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, casting

I'm using Core data on my app ok,

i have a problem when saving a number that is supposed to be an integer... when I fetch it from Core Data, it shows strange number value

I know is working because, with the test, having my idTosave = 345, it shows on results of CoreData, but when sending a value [string to int] that I know is woking as it logs the correct response, CD saves a strange value:

(Please note Im saving to entity idRef)

```
NSLog(@"resultToDisplay:: %@", self.resultsToDisplay);

//    int idToSave = 345; //if I use this line instead of intValue it saves 345 OK!
int idToSave = (int)[self.resultsToDisplay intValue];


NSLog(@"id salvada as NSINTEGER:: %d",idToSave);



//graba a CD!
[Student insertWithDataQR:[studentDataDicto objectForKey:@"name"] surname:[studentDataDicto objectForKey:@"surname"] 
 phone:[studentDataDicto objectForKey:@""] 
 dob:[studentDataDicto objectForKey:@"dob"] idRef:idToSave ...]];

[[Student defaultManagedObjectContext]save:nil];
```

log out:

```
 resultToDisplay:: 1329955200
  2012-02-26 00:36:08.597 MyGym_iPad[10867:707] id salvada as NSINTEGER:: 1329955200
```

note the value 1329955200, is correctly showed as integer and string before saving,

and to check the response I do:

```
  NSArray *studiantes = [Student all];


for ( Student *tud in studiantes) {
    NSLog(@"tu %@ ...%@",tud.studentName, tud.idRef );
}
```

so, with int 345, i see on the log 
tu.idRef == 345

but with the int from string, i see on the log
tu.idRef == -32384

so If I save from string that goes to int, I get on my response: -32384

edit:

I have subclassed my generated core data class manager file,  to save idRef as NSNumber

```
    studentData.idRef = [NSNumber  numberWithInt:idRef];
```

edit x2

to check the log i do:

```
NSArray *studiantes = [Student all];


for ( Student *tud in studiantes) {
    NSLog(@"tu %@ ...%d",tud.studentName, [tud.idRef intValue]);
}
```

but the result to that is:
-32384 ,, for my value casted to int, when saved from string

but the correct value
345,, when just sent an int directly,

Comment: so if for test purpose I send an int ::345, it saves fine, but if send an NSSTring intValue, it doesn't work,,,, I have to send an int as is what my class is design to work with, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to put it in a NSNumber:

```
NSNumber *idToSave = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.resultsToDisplay integerValue]];
```

EDIT

Actually we've reached the max value, solved with an integer 32 field.

Comment: hi, thanks, but I send an Int, and in my entity class i change the int to NSNumber, please see edit at the end of my question, thanks

Comment: If you save in a sqlite3 db, you can try to access directly to the db with a terminal and see if it correctly saved. Get the path of your db with this code : NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourDB.sqlite"];
NSLog(@"Core Data store path = \"%@\"", [storeURL path]);

Comment: hi, thanks, i just checked the sqlLite file and its saving the wrong data, the same as logged out, thanks

Comment: so what it the class of resultToDisplay?

Comment: it is probably stupid but try to make your field type as an Integer 32. The value -32384 make me think that we've reached the max value. Or try to directly save 1329955200 instead of 345.

Comment: haha, man thanks!, what a stupid detail I overlooked, its working now!, thanks again bro!

Answer (score 2):

`int` values can not be Objective C `id` objects.

Either convert your `int` to a `NSString` object or, better than that, use `NSNumber` objects to contain your `int` value.

Comment: hi, thanks, but Im already using NSNumber to save to core data my int, please see edit, what else can it be?

Comment: if you're now saving it as a `NSNumber` that's good.  How are you loading it and printing it out in your `NSLog` call, though?  Try `NSLog(@"tu %@ ...%d",tud.studentName, [tud.idRef intValue]);`

Comment: hi thanks, please check end of the question for new edit, where i show the log is using %d, thanks